# try/catch não mostra mensagem correta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exceção, wcf

Pessoal tenho um código meu do C# que tem o código:

```
Uri resultadoURL;
bool resultado = Uri.TryCreate(Configuracoes.Configuracao.URL, UriKind.Absolute, out resultadoURL) && resultadoURL.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;

if (!resultado)
    throw new Exception(String.Format("URL '{0}' não é válida!", Configuracoes.Configuracao.URL));
```

No try/catch, o ex.Message, em vez de mostrar "URL 'xxx' não é válida", está mostrando a mensagem "Mensagem uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada".

Bloco do try/catch

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        Send(state.State, ToJson(new ResultadoDaIntegracao(false, ex.Message, null)));
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Alguém sabe porque o ex.Message vem diferente?

Comment: Não seria pq seu bloco de catch mais interno não está propagando a exception?

Comment: Por que você lança uma `Exception` e não uma exceção mais específica? E por que tem um `try` dentro de um `catch`? E este último `catch` é só um exemplo, né?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Descobri o problema/solução.

Como o projeto é composto de várias DLL, ao chamar uma destas DLL, o erro apresentado por ex.Message é do processo de origem, por isto mostra a mensagem "Mensagem uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada".

O erro que eu precisava mostrar era o erro que ocorreu dentro da DLL que foi chamada.

Para isto utilizei a propriedade InnerException, que é a mensagem do erro do exception gerado dentro do destino.

O fonte ficou assim:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            Send(state.State, ToJson(new ResultadoDaIntegracao(false, ex.InnerException.Message, null)));
        else
            Send(state.State, ToJson(new ResultadoDaIntegracao(false, ex.Message, null)));
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque você não atribuiu um valor pra ele. Aí fica o erro interno (que não tem especificidade pq é padrão). Experimente definir um Exception e no catch vazio e passar o valor da mensagem que retorna em 'e' para 'ex'.

Answer (score 0):

Simulando seu exemplo Marlon Tiedt, constatei que funcionou:

*Obs: Provoquei o erro escrevendo `errorURL`.*

```
try
{
    Uri resultadoURL;
    bool resultado = Uri.TryCreate("errorURL", UriKind.Absolute, out resultadoURL) && resultadoURL.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
    if (!resultado)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("URL '{0}' não é válida!", "errorURL"));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        var e = ex;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Descobri o problema/solução. Como o projeto é composto de várias DLL, ao chamar uma destas DLL, o erro apresentado por ex.Message é do processo que chama, e o erro na verdade está dentro da propriedade InnerException, que é teoricamente é a mensagem do erro original. valeu pela ajuda pessoal.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt legal, pode editar e acrescentar isso na minha resposta se assim quiser! ou então abrir a sua resposta! fique a vontade. Acredito que quanto mais esclarecimento melhor e parabéns ...!!!